# Regular expression to match this query

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence like this:

`Well, {hero}Superman X. 123 Sr.{/hero}, the most lovable guy was hated by {lover}Louis{/lover}.`

I am using java regular exp. like this (which is not working: of course):

`Pattern search = Pattern.compile("}.*{\/")`

Actually it provides me this output:

`}Superman X. 123 Sr.{/hero}, the most lovable guy was hated by {lover}Louis{/`

When actually I want: "Superman X. 123 Sr." and then "Louis". How can this be achieved apart from running a while loop and increment the index? I can try that ..but was trying to know if there is an easier way that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better regex, but this `(\{\w+\})([\w\.\s]+)(\{/\w+\})` does your work:

```
String test = "Well, {hero}Superman X. 123 Sr.{/hero}, the most lovable guy"+
                  " was hated by {lover}Louis{/lover}.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\w+\\})([\\w\\.\\s]+)(\\{/\\w+\\})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: `{1}` is a no-op, a waste of three bytes and an entire operation. Everything is quantified as 1 by default, so specifying a quantity of 1 is redundant.

Comment: @Kolink: Thanks. Not sure, it wasn't working without it so I put it, but now when I tried, it worked :(. Removed it from the answer.

Comment: Sorry: I changed the query a bit as I was going through my document. I didn't realize that you have responded.

Comment: @Knight I updated the regex to include `.` and `space` characters. Seems to be working with your updated string. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That is because quantifiers are greedy by default. You want a lazy quantifier, so try `.*?` instead of just `.*`.

Also, you might want to capture the tag itself:

```
Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]+)\\}(.*?)\\{/\1\\}");
```

Note that I'm not 100% certain of the current syntax for a backreference in Java regexes, but that should work. You should end up with the tag name in the first captured subpattern (`hero` or `lover` in this case), and the name itself in the second subpattern.